# Constructing std::hash function which accepts any iterable type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I have tried to implement a `std::hash` function which works on any iterator type, where the user has to implement a hashing function for their type `T`.
My initial implementation of the `std::hash` function for `std::array` be seen below:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct std::hash<std::array<T, N>> {
    std::size_t operator()(const std::array<T, N>& x) const {
        auto hash_func = std::hash<T>{};
        size_t h_val{};
        for (T t : x) {
            h_val = h_val ^ hash_func(t);
        }
        return h_val;
    }
};
```

For supporting any iterator I have been trying to use sfinae, where my current implementation of a container type `is_container` can be seen below:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void> // primary declaration
struct is_container: std::false_type {}; // when all specializations fail

template <typename T>
struct is_container< // specialization
        T, // conditions:
        std::void_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T&>()))>
>: std::true_type {};

template <typename C>  // *_v value
constexpr auto is_container_v = is_container<C>::value;
```

My problem is that I can't seem to match the required parameters for the `struct std::hash<>`.

Comment: Do note that adding a specialization to `std::hash` for the the library types is UB.  You are only allowed to specialize for you own types.  I would just write your own hash functor that will work with any iterable type and give that to the things that need it.

Comment: Can't say off the top of my head how you could use `is_container` to conditionally enable a `std::hash` specialisation, but a couple things that you may or may not realise: `for (T t : x)` deep-copies all the elements - prefer `for (const T& t : x)`, and `h_val = h_val ^ hash_func(t);` is *the* classic example of collision prone hashing for multiple values - check out [boost `hash_combine`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35985960/410767).