# Pass a parameter to an unordered_map (or set) hash struct

Tags: c++, unordered-map, unordered-set, hash-function

I have the following struct:

```
array<int, 2> map_size;

struct Node{
    int id;
    array<int, 2> pos;
    vector<Node*> nbs;
    bool in_open;
    bool in_closed;
};
```

Every Node has a position (pos) that is in range of map_size (global variable).

And I'm using the following unordered map

```
struct PosHash{
    public:
    size_t operator()(array<int, 2> const& pos) const{
        return pos[1] + pos[0]*map_size[1];
    }
};

struct PosCompare{
    bool operator()(const array<int, 2>& pos1, const array<int, 2>& pos2) const{
        if (pos1[0] == pos2[0] and pos1[1] == pos2[1]){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
};

unordered_map<array<int, 2>, Node*, PosHash, PosCompare> nodes;
```

map_size is a global variable used in the hash function and allows me to get a perfect hash.
However, I would like to pass map_size as a parameter to PosHash and this way, avoid using global variables. How can I do this?

PD: map_size value is determined in execution time

Comment: How about having a ```map_size``` data member for ```PosHash```. Have it's constructor intialize it. Then pass this object to the constructor of the ```unordered_map``` (at appropriate position)

Comment: `map_size` is the key to your map.

Comment: `pos[]` are variables inside `Node`, which in turn is the mapped value inside your `unordered_map`. The hash function `PosHash` should receive key values and yield out `Node`s, that is, `pos[]`. How come the hash function needs mapped values to yield mapped values?

Comment: @User10482 I think that's the way. But I don't know how to pass the parameter in the unordered_map line (map_size is determined in execution time)

Comment: @Lingo This is for A*. In A* I get the start and goal positions as array<int, 2>, not nodes.

Comment: @BMarin: Template parameters to `unordered_map` are <Key, mapped Value, Hash Function, Predicate for comparison>. You are mapping an `array<int,2>`, presumably the `map position`, to `Node*`, have I understood correctly?

Comment: @Lingo yes, correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete program showing how to construct a `PosHash` object storing a specific value.  Note that you don't need a custom comparison - `std::array`s are compared the same way anyway.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_map>

using Pos = std::array<int, 2>;

struct PosHash {
    PosHash(int m) : m_{m} { }
    size_t operator()(const Pos& pos) const {
        return pos[1] + pos[0] * m_;
    }
    int m_;
};

int main()
{
    static constexpr size_t initial_bucket_count = 5;
    // for illustrative purposes, will just map to ints
    std::unordered_map<Pos, int, PosHash> m{initial_bucket_count, PosHash{4}};
    m[Pos{2, 3}] = 23;
    m[Pos{1, 1}] = 11;
    m[Pos{3, 1}] = 11;
    m[Pos{3, 2}] = 32;
    for (const auto& x : m)
        std::cout << x.first[0] << ',' << x.first[1] << '=' << x.second << '\n';
}
```

More generally, this is a "weak" hash function.  It may be "perfect" in producing hash values spread out enough to avoid collisions in the hash value space, but that doesn't mean you won't get collisions if you're folding that space into a lesser number of buckets.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i needed. 
I didn't know how to pass the map size to the unordered_map.

Anyways, I know this hash function is perfect as nodes with same positions are always the same node.  This Hash function returns the position in the 1-dim array of the map.

Comment: Now I'm aware that the problem is the amount of buckets, and with limited buckets it would be better to use a standard string hash function like djb2

Comment: @BMarin: oh good - I was wondering if I should try to explain further or not.  A reasonable general-purpose way to combine hashes for multi-part keys is [`hash_combine`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35985960/410767) - you'd basically say `size_t seed = 0; hash_combine(seed, pos[0]); hash_combine(seed, pos[1]);` then use `seed` as your hash value.

Answer (score 1):

You can have `map_size` as a data member inside `PosHash` struct.

```
struct PosHash{
    public:
    size_t operator()(array<int, 2> const& pos) const{
        return pos[1] + pos[0]*map_size[1];
    }

    // Contructor that initializes the data member
    PosHash(std::intializer_list<int> map_dim) : map_size(map_dim) {
      // Other stuff
    };
    
    std::array<int, 2> map_size; // data member of the struct
};
```

Then you can construct a `PosHash` object with required `map_size` array. Pass this object to your `unordered_map`

```
PosHash myPosHash({1, 2});

std::unordered_map<array<int, 2>, Node*, PosHash, PosCompare> nodes(\\intial args\\, myPosHash);
```

Check out the different available constructors for `std::unordered_map` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/unordered_map/). You need to explicitly specify all the arguments before the hasher argument. Those would depend on your needs.
The simplest I can think of is

```
nodes(0, myPosHash);  //initial #buckets, hasher object
```

Comment: And how do I initialize the unordered_map?

Comment: @BMarin Added. You can have the constructor for ```PosHash``` and other details your way. Hope this helps.

Comment: Tony Delroy's answer has the correct way to initialize the map, which differs slightly, thanks anyway!