# How to get a hash from variadic arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, hash, tuples, variadic-templates

I want to create a random number generation util for C++ and I want to create a method `SetSeed` that would generate and set a seed from input variadic arguments.
I have such methods:

```
void SetSeedDirectly(int seed);

template<typename... Args>
void SetSeed(Args... args);
```

And the `SetSeed` method must generate a seed from `args` and call the `SetSeedDirectly` method. But I don't know how to generate a seed. I guess that I should use `std::hash` to generate a hash(seed) from args.
I know how to get a hash from one value, but not from multiple values.
I've tried to use `tuple`:

```
template <typename... Args>
void SetSeed(Args... args) {
  std::tuple<Args...> t(args...);
  std::hash<std::tuple<Args...>> h;
  size_t seed = h(t);
  this->SetSeedDirectly(static_cast<uint32_t>(seed));
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work and compiler outputs errors like this:

```
'std::hash<std::tuple<int,std::string>>::hash(void)': function was implicitly deleted because a base class invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'std::_Conditionally_enabled_hash<_Kty,false>::_Conditionally_enabled_hash(void)'
```

Hope for your help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Any particular reason [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) ?

Comment: There is no such constructor for `std::hash<std::tuple<...>>` which is why the code fails. Look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) for all possible template arguments that `std::hash<X>` can take.

Comment: Consider `boost::hash_combine` - the implementation's only a few lines and can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985960/c-why-is-boosthash-combine-the-best-way-to-combine-hash-values) along with some commentary on quality.  It combines the hashes of multiple objects into one overall hash.

Comment: @TonyDelroy, thanks, it's good choice for me