# Unordered map of unordered set in C++ 11

Tags: c++, unordered-map, unordered-set

I wanted to implement something, that maps an unordered set of integers to an integer value. Some kind of C++ equivalent of Python dict, which has sets as keys and ints as values.

So far I used `std::map<std::set<int>, int> set_lookup;` but from what I understood this is unnecessarily slow as it uses trees. I don't care about the ordering, only speed is important.

From what I have understand, the desired structure is `std::unordered_map<std::unordered_set<int>, int, hash> set_lookup;` which needs a hash function to work.

Is this the right approach? And how would a minimum running example look like? I couldn't find how the hash part should look like.

Comment: As an academic exercise ("how to hash an unordered set of integers") this can be answered. However, before that, what specific real-world problem are you trying to solve? There may be a better implementation than a map of sets. Do all possible sets have a unique integer assignment? Or can a given integer be mapped to multiple different sets?

Comment: If I try to use a set as a dict key in Python, I encounter "TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'". Don't you?

Comment: At the least, I would convert the set to a sorted vector...

Comment: @molbdnilo You must freeze the set in Python (see `frozenset`). It doesn't make sense if the keys can change.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear whether you ask about the syntax for defining a hash function, or about how to define a mathematically good hash for a set of ints.

Anyway - in case it is the former, here is how you should technically define a hash function for your case:

```
template <>
struct hash<std::unordered_set<int>>
{
    std::size_t operator()(const std::unordered_set<int>& k) const
    {
        using std::size_t;
        using std::hash;
        using std::string;
    
        // ...
        // Here you should create and return a meaning full hash value:
        return 5;
    }
};
    
void main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::unordered_set<int>, int> m;
}
```

Having written that, I join the other comments about whether it is a good direction to solve your problem.
You haven't described your problem, so I cannot answer that.

Answer (score 0):

> I understood [`std::map<std::set<int>, int> set_lookup;`] is unnecessarily slow as it uses trees.

> Is [`std::unordered_map<std::unordered_set<int>, int, hash>`] the right approach?

It depends.  If your keys are created *then not changed*, and you want to be able to do a lot of lookups very fast, then a hash-table based approach would indeed be good, but you'll need two things for that:

- to be able to hash keys
- to be able to compare keys

To hash keys, deciding on a good hash function is a bit of an art form.  A rarely bad - but sometimes slower than necessary - approach is to use boost `hash_combine` (which is short enough that you can copy it into your code - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35985960/410767) for the implementation).  If your integer values are already quite random across most of their bits, though, simply XORing them together would produce a great hash.  If you're not sure, use `hash_combine` or a better hash (e.g. MURMUR32).  The time taken to hash will depend on the time to traverse, and traversing an `unordered_set` typically involves a linked list traversal (which typically jumps around in memory pages and is CPU  cache unfriendly).  The best way to store the values for fast traversal is in contiguous memory - i.e. a `std::vector<>`, or `std::array<>` if the size is known at compile time.

The other thing you need to do is compare keys for equality: that also works fastest when elements in the key are contiguous in memory, and consistently ordered.  Again, a sorted `std::vector<>` or `std::array<>` would be best.

That said, if the sets for your keys are large, and you can compromise on a statistical guarantee of key equality, you could use e.g. a 256-bit hash and code *as if* hash collisions *always* correspond to key equality.  That's often not an acceptable risk, but if your hash is not collision prone and you have e.g. a 256 bit hash, a CPU could run flat-chat for millennia hashing distinct keys and still be *unlikely* to produce the same hash even once, so it is a use I've seen even financial firms use in their core in-house database products, as it can save *so* much time.

If you're tempted by that compromise, you'd want `std::unordered_map<HashValue256, std::pair<int, std::vector<int>>>`.  To find the `int` associated with a set of integers, you'd hash them first, then do a lookup.  It's easy to write a hash function that produces the same output for a `set` or sorted `vector<>` or `array<>`, as you can present the elements to something like `hash_combine` in the same sorted order during traversal (i.e. just `size_t seed = 0; for (auto& element : any_sorted_container) hash_combine(seed, element);`).  Storing the `vector<int>` means you can traverse the `unordered_map` later if you want to find all the key "sets" - if you don't need to do that (e.g. you're only ever looking up the `int`s by keys known to the code at the time, and you're comfortable with the statistical improbability of a good hash colliding, you don't even need to store the keys/vectors): `std::unordered_map<HashValue256, int>`.