# Overriding qHash() using a hashing function without a seed

Tags: c++, macos, qt, core-foundation, qhash

I'm trying to write an overload of `qHash` where the hash will be computed using a Core Foundation type.

Apple provides the following function for this: `CFHashCode CFHash(CFTypeRef cf);`

This is all well and good, but `qHash` requires a second argument, a seed value. While my code can compile if I implement `qHash` without it, the `qHash` documentation has the following warning:

> Note: In Qt 6 it is possible to define a qHash() overload taking only one argument; support for this is deprecated. Starting with Qt 7, it will be mandatory to use a two-arguments overload.

So rather than relying on deprecated behavior, I'd like to include the seed argument.

The question is, how do I calculate the hash when the third party hashing function I'm reliant on doesn't use a seed?

Is returning something like `CFHash(cf) ^ seed` acceptable? Or perhaps a better option is `CFHash(cf) ^ qHash(seed, 0)`?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/50978188