# Is std::unordered_map a good candidate for recording if I have already "dealt with" an object?

Tags: c++

I have a structure called Col:

```
struct Col
{
   Object* o1;
   Object* o2;
   Object* o3;

   bool operator==(const Col &other) const
   { 
       return o1 == o1 && o2 == o2 && o3 == o3;
   }
};
```

I define a hash on this:

```
template <>
struct std::hash<Col>
{
  std::size_t operator()(const Col& k) const
  {
    using std::size_t;

    std::hash<void> void_hash;

    std::size_t res = void_hash(k.o1) + void_hash(k.o2) + void_hash(k.o3;

    return res;
  }
};
```

I then have a long `std::vector` of `Col` objects which contains duplicates (per my definition of equality), and I wish to "process" each unique element only once.

This is what I do:

```
std::unordered_map<Col, bool> done_list;

for (Col c : col_list)
{
    if (done_list.find(c) == done_list.end())
    {
        process(c);

        done_list[c] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Is this a reasonable way to check for whether the same collection of objects has been processed already?  Would a sparse matrix be better?

Comment: You don't even need a map if the value is just going to be a bool. Just use a (unordered_set where the presence alone indicates if you've processed.

Comment: This makes no sense if you are going to process every object once. I assume you have some kind of condition so that some objects are not processed at all? Otherwise, why use anything on top of the loop?

Comment: @Nelfeal OP probably have duplicates (according to its equality function) in its vector. OP Can you say in the description your vector have duplicates?

Comment: Does the hash function look reasonable btw - I haven't really used std::hash before.

Comment: It depends on how you allocate your objects. If you create/delete/create often, chances are that your objects end up at the same address, thus creating potential conflicts. You need to monitor for your particular use.

Comment: You're hashing *pointers*, but I would guess you actually want to hash the *data*.

Comment: If a Col object has the same pointers as another but o1 and o2 are swapped, are they the "same" object?  (Your hash says yes).  Also, why `using std::size_t` and then qualify size_t with its namespace anyway?  :)

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis if they are not the same object, what would you advise for the hash function?  And it's inexperience on the std::size_t thing, I don't actually know what using std::size_t does.

Comment: @Omroth Then what you should be doing is to first make a `std::hash<Object>` specialization and in `std::hash<Col>` you would use `std::hash<Object>` on the dereferenced pointers in such a way that the ordering of the objects matters. Many people use [`boost::hash_combine`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35985960/7582247) for this.

Answer (score 6):

You approach is OK, but you can simplify it a bit by using [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) instead of `std::unordered_map`.

The set will contain the values you already processed.

```
#include <unordered_set>

std::unordered_set<Col> done_list;

for (Col const & c : col_list)
{
    if (done_list.find(c) == done_list.end())
    {
        process(c);
        done_list.insert(c);
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Note that I used `const &` in the ranged for-loop to avoid copy and mutation of `c`. You can drop the `const` if need to mutate it.

If you are using c++20 you can use [`std::unordered_set::contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/contains) to make the check even simpler:

```
    if (done_list.contains(c) == false)
    // ...
```

Another variation takes advantage of the overload of [`std::unordered_set::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert) that returns a pair where the `bool` `second` indicates whether the item was inserted (it will not be inserted if it already exists in the set):

```
    auto[it, inserted] = done_list.insert(c);
    if (inserted)
    {
        process(c);
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: If you are looking for performance, a `vector` might be faster than an `unordered_set` when there are only a few hundreds element because of caching.

Comment: Note that C++20 added [`std::unordered_set::contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/contains) so you don't need `find` + comparison to `end`

Comment: @Dorian that's true, but since we don't know the number of elements I prefered the to use a set as a more general solution. I would  use a `std::vector` as an optimizd version after profiling.

Comment: @wohlstad Oups, I didn't think you noticed so I added an answer too :-) Oh well, it still has a simplification in it so I'll leave it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's OK, I liked your idea of storing pointers in the set :-)

Comment: Hmm, wait a second. I just realized that my pointer idea will not do what OP wants with those pointer member variables. :-/ I'll delete my answer to not lead him/her astray.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you might be right, it's hard to know for sure without additional context.

Comment: @wohlstad True. I now returned to make it work with the pointers. Hopefully I got it right this time :-)

Answer (score 3):

- What you need is rather some kind of `set` which stores only one of each element.
- You also do not need to store the `Col`s in the `set`. It's enough with pointers to the elements.

I suggest using an `unordered_set` so first we need a hasher and a comparator for the pointers:

```cpp
struct colptr_hash {
    const bool operator()(const Col* col) const {
        return std::hash<Col>{}(*col);
    }
};

struct colptr_equal {
    const bool operator()(const Col* lhs, const Col* rhs) const {
        return *lhs == *rhs;
    }
};
```

Then the actual usage:

```cpp
std::unordered_set<Col*, colptr_hash, colptr_equal> done_list;

for (Col& c : col_list) {           // take by reference
    // try to insert this Col*
    auto [it, inserted] = done_list.emplace(&c);

    if (!inserted) continue;        // already processed, try next

    // never processed, go ahead:
    process(c);
}
```