# C++ - Hash/Map a std::vector<uint64_t> in a single uint64_t

Tags: c++, hash, c++17, hash-function

I need to map a `std::vector<uint64_t>` to a single `uint64_t`. It is possible to do? I thought to use a hash function. Is that a solution?

For example, this vector:

```
std::vector<uint64_t> v {
  16377,
  2631694347470643681,
  11730294873282192384
}
```

should be converted into one `uint64_t`.

If a hash function is not a good solution (e.g. high percentage of collision) there is an alternative to do this mapping?

Comment: Get a few of the values (say the first 3), multiply each with a number that's a prime. And you have a new uint64_t value that will do as hash. Don't mind the overflows something todo with modulo 2^n not sharing a foctor with prime numbers. How many numbers you need depends on how unique the values you have in the vector are.

Comment: what are you going to do with the hash? Is the vector to be inserted to an unordered_set?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511347/a-good-hash-function-for-a-vector

Comment: Another idea is to use multiple hashes for the same vector so that the probabilty of collision decreases. Like how bloomfilters work.

Comment: Note that hashing is not compression. Compression implies some ability to decompress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to hash a std::vector<uint64_t> to a single uint64_t. It is possibile to do?

Yes, variable length hash functions exist, and it's possible to implement them in C++.

C++ standard library comes with a few hash functions, but unfortunately not for vector (other than for the bool specialisation). We can reuse the hash function provided for string views, but this is a bit of a cludge:

```
const char* data = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(v.data());
std::size_t size = v.size() * sizeof(v[0]);
std::hash<std::string_view> hash;
std::cout << hash(std::string_view(data, size));
```

Note that using this is reasonable only in the case `std::has_unique_object_representations_v` is true of the element type of vector. I think it's reasonable to assume that to be the case for `std::uint64_t`.

A caveat when using standard library hash functions is that they don't have exact specification and as such you cannot rely on hashes being identical across separate systems. You should use another hash function if that is a concern.

Comment: Are you sure that `string_view` hash would not stop hashing if it sees embedded zeros (which are very likely for small integers put into `uint64_t`)?

Comment: @AlexGuteniev The hash function isn't exactly specified. Technically, it could be as bad as hashing the first character or whatever. But if we assume a reasonable implementation, then given that strings may contain null terminators, and given that string views aren't guranteed to contain any null terminators I don't see a reason why the hash function would stop at the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `std::map<std::vector<uint64_t>, uint64_t>`, create a compare function for your vectors and just keep adding them to a map while incrementing a counter.

That counter will be your `hash` value.

Comment: It's possible I don't understand this answer, but how is a naive histogram going to have a low chance of collision?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica my suggestion doesn't handle collisions, that's correct. It has a limit of whatever `uint64_t` can hold.

Answer (score 0):

The comment above in code :

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

static std::array<size_t,5> primes = { 3,5,7,11,13 };

static std::uint64_t hash(const std::vector<std::uint64_t>& v)
{
    std::uint64_t hash = v[0];
    for (size_t n = 1; n < std::min(primes.size(), v.size()); ++n) hash += (primes[n]*v[n]);
    return hash;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint64_t> v{ 16377,  2631694347470643681,  11730294873282192384 };
    std::cout << hash(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fixed the hash function, should add the multiplications.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks missed that, fixed :)