# Hash function for creating a generic hash table in Java (for learning purposes)

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashtable

If you were creating creating a generic hash table in Java (assume it didn't already have one), then how would you implement its default hash function?  I know you can pass one in (via an interface), but most data structures have defaults.

**My Attempt:**

As Java generics require reference types, and all reference types in Java implement hashCode(), I figured that you could just use `T.hashCode() % backingArraySize` as the hash function, and that this would be sufficient. After all, the implementer of any type you may store in the hash table should give their type an appropriate hashCode() function, right?

**Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: Define **better**. There are many ways of implementing an hash table (open addressing, chaining, kind of buckets, etc) and there are multiple kind of data and distribution which could lead to different hashing function requirements.

Comment: Interesting... Why would the implementation matter; whether you're open addressing or chaining, less collisions is still more efficient right?

Comment: Why generic? Since all classes implement `hashCode()`, just make the parameter `Object` and be done with it. Generics (which offers type bounds) serves no purpose.

Comment: By the way, `hashCode()` can be negative, in that case `hashcode() % size` can also be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my hashtable implementation I decided to use plain `hashCode() % backingArraySize` (i. e. yours suggestion) when the algorithm isn't a subject of [primary clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_clustering) and `hashCode() * 2654435761` (the constant is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/665545/648955)) when it is, i. e. for linear hashing implementation. The reason is that many default `hashCode()` implementations don't distribute values across full `int` range well (all numberic boxed types, `String`, `List`), and when the keys are somehow biased linear hashing may suffer from primary clustering.