# sort huge array with small number of repeating keys

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, c++11, stdvector

I want to sort a huge array, say 10^8 entries of type `X` with at most `N` different keys, where `N` is ~10^2. Because I don't know the range or spacing of the elements, count sort is not an option. So my best guess so far is to use a hash map for the counts like so

```
std::unordered_map< X, unsigned > counts;
for (auto x : input)
    counts[x]++;
```

This works ok-ish and is ~4 times faster than 3-way quicksort, but I'm a nervous person and it's still not fast enough.

I wonder: am I missing something? Can I make better use of the fact that `N` is known in advance? Or is it possible to tune the hash map to my needs?

---

**EDIT** An additional pre-condition is that the input sequence is badly sorted and the frequency of the keys is about the same.

Comment: Maybe call [reserve(N)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/reserve/) before starting to add to the hash table?

Comment: Are the keys consecutive? Do you know only their number in advance, or also their values?

Comment: @IVlad I have tried that. Makes virtually no difference for my map implementation, however.

Comment: @dlask I only know the number of different keys. The numbers may be non-consecutive and the key values are not known.

Comment: `for (auto const& x : input)` would avoid copying it should be faster for you

Comment: Do you know anything at all about the elements (other than there are ~ 100 distinct ones)?

Comment: Note that your code does not *sort* the array, it only counts *frequences* of the elements. I guess it is enough for you.

Comment: You can try a hash table more optimized than `std::unordered_map`, such as Google's [`dense_hash_map`](http://sparsehash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dense_hash_map.html). It also sometimes helps to use better hash function than `std::hash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STL implementations are often not perfect in terms of performance (no holy wars, please).

If you know a guaranteed and sensible upper on the number of unique elements (*N*), then you can trivially implement your own hash table of size *2^s* >> *N*. Here is how I usually do it myself:

```
int size = 1;
while (size < 3 * N) size <<= 1;
//Note: at least 3X size factor, size = power of two
//count = -1 means empty entry
std::vector<std::pair<X, int>> table(size, make_pair(X(), -1));
auto GetHash = [size](X val) -> int { return std::hash<X>()(val) & (size-1); };

for (auto x : input) {
  int cell = GetHash(x);
  bool ok = false;
  for (; table[cell].second >= 0; cell = (cell + 1) & (size-1)) {
    if (table[cell].first == x) { //match found -> stop
      ok = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!ok) {             //match not found -> add entry on free place
    table[cell].first = x;
    table[cell].second = 0;
  }
  table[cell].second++;  //increment counter
}
```

On MSVC2013, it improves time from 0.62 secs to 0.52 secs compared to your code, given that *int* is used as type *X*.

Also, we can choose a faster hash function. Note however, that the choice of hash function depends heavily on the properties of the input. Let's take [Knuth's multiplicative hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/665545/556899):

```
auto GetHash = [size](X val) -> int { return (val*2654435761) & (size-1); };
```

It further improves time to 0.34 secs.

As a conclusion: **do you really want to reimplement standard data structures to achieve a 2X speed boost?**

Notes: Speedup may be entirely different on another compiler/machine. You may have to do some hacks if your type *X* is not POD.

Comment: Better to use dense_hash_map than roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

Counting sort really would by best, but isnt applicable due to unknown range or spacing.

Seems to be easily parallelized with fork-join, e.g. [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/parallel.html).

You could also try a more efficient, handrolled hashmap. Unorded_map typically uses linked lists to counter potentially bad hash functions. The  memory overhead of linked lists may hurt performance if the hashtable doesnt fit into L1 cache. [Closed Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) may use less memory. Some hints for optimizing:

- Closed Hashing with linear probing and without support for removal
- power of two sized hashtable for bit shifting instead of modulo (division requires multiple cycles and there is only one hardware divider per core)
- Low LoadFactor (entries through size) to minimize collisions. Thats a tradeof between memory usage and number of collisions. A LoadFactor over 0.5 should be avoided. A hashtable-size of 256 seems suitable for 100 entries.
- cheapo hash function. You havent shown the type of `X`, so perhaps a cheaper hash function could outweigh more collisions.

Answer (score 0):

I would look to store items in a sorted vector, as about 100 keys, would mean inserting into the vector would only occur 1 in 10^6 entries. Lookup would be processor efficient bsearch in vector