# 31-bit Bijective (Perfect) Hash algorithm

Tags: algorithm, hash, crc, perfect-hash, bijection

**What I need**

I need an algorithm that produces a bijective output. I have a 31-bit input and need a pseudo-random 31-bit output.

**What I have considered**

CRCs are bijective within their bit-width.

I have looked on Google and can find the polynomials for this, but not the tables or algorithm.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I need a CRC-31 algorithm using polynomial say 0x737e312b, or any bijective function that will do what I need.

**NOTE**

I found the following code, but I unfortunately don't have the tools to compile and run it.

Comment: Since the output is the same range as the input, you could use the input as the output

Comment: Do you mean literally output = input? That isn't what I want. I'm looking for a pseudo-randomization of the input.

Comment: So you  want to perform a random permutation of the input?

Comment: There are 32 and 64 bit variants that are faster than CRC listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664014/what-integer-hash-function-are-good-that-accepts-an-integer-hash-key/12996028#12996028). It should be possible to build a 31 bit variant from this.

Comment: I want to perform a bijective permutation of the input. 31-bit bit input -> bijective hash (31-bit) -> 31-bit output.

Comment: I assume with "bijective" you mean you also need a way to "undo" the hash operation. Actually I wouldn't know how to do that with a CRC.

Comment: I don't need to undo it. I just need a 1:1 mapping where the output "appears somewhat random" as regards the input.

Comment: But you require that there are no collisions? (Meaning, no input may produce the same output as another input.)

Comment: That is correct. Bijective, no collisions. CRC is bijective over its bit width.

Comment: `I don't need to undo it.` Given a bijection, you won't be able to help to be able to.

Comment: Undoing is not the point. Getting it done is the point :-)

Comment: Whoever voted to close this... may I suggest you read the help center notes on what is on-topic.

Comment: You can use any bijective function. Are you asking what bijective functions exist, or which one is better, or how to implement one, or what?

Comment: I haven't found much by way of bijective algorithms other than CRC. If there is a workable algorithm that can do what I want, that would be great :-)

Comment: You could just XOR the input with any random 31-bit number.

Comment: True, but an input of say {1, 2, 3} would result in an output where only the 2 least significant bits change. CRC will produce a somewhat random looking difference between these 3 numbers (e.g. 2583214201, 2337085335, 871461106}.

Comment: Or, you could multiply by an (odd)  prime mod 2**31

Comment: I was *just* playing with that idea. Is that guaranteed to be bijective? Would the prime need to be within or without the range?

Comment: Well, try it! (just takes 15 minutes or so)

Comment: The multiply-and-mod-*n* approach doesn't even require a prime; any odd number should do. And this can be combined with XOR-ing for a better semblance of randomness of successive integers. (You can even do a few alternating rounds of both.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any hash function `hash`, you can do:

```
function bijectiveHash31(int val) {
    val &= 0x7FFFFFFF; //make sure it's 31 bits
    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
        // the high bits affect the low bits
        val ^= hash(val>>15) & 32767;
        // rotate bits
        val = ((val&32767)<<16) | ((val>>15)&65535);
    }
    return val;
}
```

This is a Feistel structure, which forms the basis of many ciphers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher

If you need it to be fast and you don't need it to be super good, then this works fine:

```
function bijectiveHash31(int val) {
    val = ((val*RANDOM_ODD_NUMBER) + RANDOM_NUMBER) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
    val ^= (val>>15);
    val ^= (val>>8);
    return val;
}
```

In both of these cases, it's not *too* difficult to figure out how you could undo each elementary operation, which shows that the whole hash is bijective.  If you need help establishing that for the multiplication, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: An alternative way to ensure it is bijective (doesn't have collisions), you could loop over all possible inputs and for each output set a bit in a 256 MiB bit field. At the end, check that all bits are set. With a decently fast programming language (C, Java,...), this only takes a few seconds.

Comment: Using the second algorithm as the `hash` function for the first algorithm yields particularly impressive results.

Comment: FYI I implemented 64, 48, 44, 32, 16 bit version [here](https://github.com/thomasmueller/minperf/blob/master/src/main/java/org/minperf/utils/RandomSetGenerator.java#L170). But not 31 bit.