# Simple implementation of hash functions

Tags: c#, .net, hash

I am studying hash algorithms. I've learned how to use hash functions and methods implemented in many frameworks, but I need know how to make my own implementation of a hash function or the basics steps for implementing one simple hash function.

Where would i find information about that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595/what-is-a-good-hash-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many hash algorithms that can be implemented, there are a bunch provided in the .Net library itself. However, if you want to implement one you need to pick an algorithm first.
The following is an implementation of [Tiger Hash](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149061/A-Tiger-Hash-Implementation-for-C). Another hash function implementation is by [Davy Landman](http://landman-code.blogspot.com.au/2009/02/c-superfasthash-and-murmurhash2.html). Looking at the code might help you get started.