# How to select a good hashing function (for a hashtable)

Tags: performance, hashtable

I was wondering how one would best approach the task of deciding upon the operations a hashing function should perform on it's input, based on the probable input format of course.

Are there any rule(book)s i have yet to find?

How could i estimate the cost of such a function?

Can i somehow foresee the likelihood of collisions knowing the charset used for inputs?

Thanks for your food for my thought in advance. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good Hash Function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595/what-is-a-good-hash-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...

Hi Gung Foo,

just take a look at **CRC32** vs **FNV1A_Yorikke** face-off at:

http://www.sanmayce.com/Fastest_Hash/index.html#KT_torture3

> How could i estimate the cost of such a function?

In short: heavy & versatile keys/loads.
Generally a hash (table-look-up) function has three major aspects to consider:

- Collisions both dispersion and MAX depthness of the fattest slot;
- Warm-up time i.e. starting cost/overhead;
- Linear speed.

Comment: I love your site! Can you comment on "the likelihood of collisions knowing the charset used for inputs"?

Comment: Two things here:
  
- I said versatile keys but I myself didn't test hashers thoroughly i.e. I need more type of keys;

- AFAIU the Birthday Paradox is badly interpreted - there is a convergence of dispersion quality for good hashers from some point e.g. 10:1, this is what I mean: you don't need some super precise collision-wise hash when your keys are >> or >= slots, when your keys are << or <= slots then perfect hashing has priority but in my view CRC32 is the most useful for comparing the collision quality for both cases above.

Last night I updated the hash page with **FNV1A_Yoshimitsu**.

Comment: Well, last night I made a versatile hash test (in C) which covers several top-gun hashers and 38 different keys.  

You all are welcome to benchmark it at: http://www.overclock.net/t/1319572/benchmarking-the-fastest-hash-function/0_20#post_18495990
  
I would be glad for revealing how Intel vs AMD and Intel 12.1 compiler vs Microsoft 16 (VS2010) compiler combinations behave with your help.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule of thumb with hashcode generation is that the resulting value be as unique as possible. Two things that are desirable in a hashcode/hashfunction

1. **The hashcode is desired to be as unique (and as small) as possible**. That being said,(in an ideal world) using a data member whose datatype is small on footprint and that can be guaranteed to be unique for any instance of the value is a fast an efficient way to arrive at a hashcode. This sometimes is however, not a safe practice.
2. The hash function should be [perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) i.e. should be able to generate a unique value, all values being generated within a small range.