# Using "constexpr" to use string literal for template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, string-literals, constexpr

I have written some code to cast `const char*` to `int` by using `constexpr` and thus I can use a `const char*` as a template argument. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

class conststr
{
    public:
        template<std::size_t N>
        constexpr conststr(const char(&STR)[N])
        :string(STR), size(N-1)
        {}

        constexpr conststr(const char* STR, std::size_t N)
        :string(STR), size(N)
        {}

        constexpr char operator[](std::size_t n)
        {
            return n < size ? string[n] : 0;
        }

        constexpr std::size_t get_size()
        {
            return size;
        }

        constexpr const char* get_string()
        {
            return string;
        }

        //This method is related with Fowler–Noll–Vo hash function
        constexpr unsigned hash(int n=0, unsigned h=2166136261)
        {
            return n == size ? h : hash(n+1,(h * 16777619) ^ (string[n]));
        }

    private:
        const char* string;
        std::size_t size;
};

// output function that requires a compile-time constant, for testing
template<int N> struct OUT
{
    OUT() { std::cout << N << '\n'; }
};

int constexpr operator "" _const(const char* str, size_t sz)
{
    return conststr(str,sz).hash();
}

int main()
{
    OUT<"A dummy string"_const> out;
    OUT<"A very long template parameter as a const char*"_const> out2;
}
```

In this example code, type of `out` is `OUT<1494474505>` and type of `out2` is `OUT<106227495>`. Magic behind this code is `conststr::hash()` it is a `constexpr` recursion that uses [FNV Hash function](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/). And thus it creates an integral hash for const char* which is hopefully a unique one.

I have some questions about this method:

1. Is this a safe approach to use? Or can this approach be an evil in a specific use?
2. Can you write a better hash function that creates different integer for each string without being limited to a number of chars? (in my method, the length is long enough)
3. Can you write a code that implicitly casts `const char*` to `int constexpr` via `conststr` and thus we will not need aesthetically ugly (and also time consumer) `_const` user-defined string literal? For example `OUT<"String">` will be legal (and cast "String" to integer).

Any help will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: If my answer 'resolves' your question, can mark it as accepted ? Otherwise, you can comment it (again)!

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I always forget to do so :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although your method is very interesting, it is not really a way to pass a string literal as a template argument. In fact, it is a generator of template argument based on string literal, which is not the same: you cannot retrieve `string` from `hashed_string`... It kinda defeats the whole interest of string literals in templates.

**EDIT** : the following was right when the hash used was the weighted sum of the letters, which is not the case after the edit of the OP.

> You can also have problems with your [hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595/what-is-a-good-hash-function), as stated by mitchnull's answer. This may be another big problem with your method, the collisions. For example:
>
> ```
> // Both outputs 3721
> OUT<"0 silent"_const> out;
> OUT<"7 listen"_const> out2;
> ```

As far as I know, you cannot pass a string literal in a template argument straightforwardly in the current standard. However, you can "fake" it. Here's what I use in general:

```
struct string_holder              //
{                                 // All of this can be heavily optimized by
    static const char* asString() // the compiler. It is also easy to generate
    {                             // with a macro.
        return "Hello world!";    //
    }                             //
};                                //
```

Then, I pass the "fake string literal" via a type argument:

```
template<typename str>
struct out
{
    out()
    {
        std::cout << str::asString() << "\n";
    }
};
```

**EDIT2**: you said in the comments you used this to distinguish between several specializations of a class template. The method you showed is valid for that, but you can also use tags:

```
// tags
struct myTag {};
struct Long {};
struct Float {};

// class template
template<typename tag>
struct Integer
{
    // ...
};
template<> struct Integer<Long> { /* ... */ };

// use
Integer<Long> ...;  // those are 2
Integer<Float> ...; // different types
```

Comment: Synxis, I edited my code. My hash function was an unprofessional one, now it is using Fowler–Noll–Vo hash function. I believe this function does not have the same problem. And I could not understand your first paragraph that about ´string´ from ´hashed_string´?

Comment: You do not pass the string to  `OUT`, but the result of `hash()`. I don't think you can transform this value to a string... So, you cannot have `OUT` outputting the string you wrote between the brackets.

Comment: Oh I see. Actually that's not a problem for me (of course your point is valid) because I want to make templates that work like this: let's say we have a template named Integer<>, Integer<"long"> will be something different than Integer<"short"> and I will specialize my template to behave so.

Comment: Ok, if it is want you want (but still a valid point ;) ). Are such string "ids" ("long", "short", etc...) in a fixed number (finite, like 10-20 different ids) ?

Comment: Actually yes, and I believe they should be finite because I specialize every single of those templates manually. I can use Integer<1> (which symbolizes Integer<"short"> let's say), and Integer<2> (which symbolizes Integer<"long"> let's say) but don't you think that using string literals are aesthetically better and easier to read. One can forget what Integer<1> is, but Integer<"short"> is self-explanatory.

Comment: You can use tags. I will put that in my answer.

Comment: Yeah thank you for reminding this method too. I have once considered something similar, but did not write a code because since I am using namespace, tags' names also get long. For example let's say I am writing my code in "nmsp" namespace, user shall write nmsp::Integer<nmsp::Long>; which is nearly same (in terms of length) with nmsp::Integer<"long"_const> and I don't mind using C++11, because my code will not work without C++11 anyway.

Comment: Good point. I prefer the tags, because it is more "aesthetic" than the literal version, but that choice is up to you. You can also choose a different literal name, for example `_tag`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the pattern that I am using for template const string parameters.

`class F {
  static constexpr const char conststr[]= "some const string";
  TemplateObject<conststr> instance;
};`

see :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18031951/782168