# Trying to pass string literals as template arguments

Tags: c++, string, templates, c++11, literals

I'm trying to find a comfortable way to pass string literals as template arguments. I'm not caring about supporting the widest possible number of compilers, I'm using the latest version of g++ with `--std=c++0x`.

I've tried a lot of possible solutions but all have disappointed me. I'm sort of giving up, but first I'd like to know *why* a couple of them failed.

Here they are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct String {
    char const *m_sz;

    constexpr String(char const *a_sz)
        :
    m_sz(a_sz) {}

    char const *operator () () const {
        return m_sz;
    }
};

template<class _rstr>
string const Get() {
    return _rstr();
}

int main() {
    cout << Get<String("hello")>() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct String {
    char const *m_sz;

    constexpr String(char const *a_sz)
        :
    m_sz(a_sz) {}
};

template<String const &_rstr>
string const Get() {
    return _rstr.m_sz;
}

int main() {
    String constexpr str = "hello";
    cout << Get<str>() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The goal was to find a comfortable way to pass a string literal to the useless Get function, which returns its template argument as an std::string object.

EDIT: sorry, maybe my main question isn't clear. My question is: why do those two snippets fail?

Comment: In the first case, `String("hello")` is a value, not a type, so it cannot be passed to the template `Get<>` which expects a type.  In the second case, C++11 doesn't allow arbitrary user-defined types (like `String`) to be template parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

re: your OP: `I'd like to know why a couple of them failed.`

The comment by @NatanReed is correct:

- Your first snippet fails because `Get` needs a `TYPE` and is given an `object`.
- Your second snippet fails because it is illegal to define a template argument as reference to an object.

  - until C++2003, that is.  Then `reference to an object` became legal.

Template arguments must be constants from a limited set of types.

- See: ISO/IEC 14882-2003 §14.1: Template parameters
- See: ISO/IEC 14882-2003 §14.3.2: Template non-type arguments

And even then, the `String constexpr str = "hello";` must have external linkage.  So putting it on the stack inside of `main()` is not going to work.

Give this a try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct String {
    char const *m_sz;

    constexpr String(char const *a_sz)
        :
    m_sz(a_sz) {}
};

template<String const &_rstr>
string const Get() {
    return _rstr.m_sz;
}

extern String constexpr globally_visible_str = "hello";
int main() {
    cout << Get<globally_visible_str>() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can't use string literals as a template argument, for the
simple reason that it's unspecified whether two instances of a
literal with the same text are the same object or not.  In other
words, given:

```
template <char const* str>
class TC {};

TC< "xyz" > v1;
TC< "xyz" > v2;
```

It would be unspecified whether `v1` and `v2` had the same type
or not.

You can use `char const[]` variables as template arguments,
however, since they have a defined address:

```
template <char const* str>
class TC {};

extern char const xyz[] = "xyz";
TC< xyz > v1;
TC< xyz > v2;
```

In this case, `v1` and `v2` are guaranteed to have the same
type.

EDIT:

I think C++11 removes the need for the `extern` on the
definition of the string, at least if the string and the
instantiation are all in the same translation unit.  I'm not
sure, however; the one time I did something like this, I didn't
have access to C++11.

Comment: I can confirm the limitation of `extern` was removed because I've tried without it and it works (it was one of my several attempts).

Also, I know I can't pass string literals directly but I was trying to circumvent this in some way, and probably failed.

Comment: Clarification: declaring a variable with external linkage (typically a global one) is not "comfortable" to me. Being able to use some sort of `String` adapter, like in my two snippets, is much more comfortable.

Answer (score 8):

I know the post is old but I haven't found any solution for this problem here, and maybe someone would be interested in my workaround:

```
template <int N>
constexpr int string_literal_length(const char (&str)[N]) {
   return N - 1;
}

template <int PassedLength, int CountedLength, char... Characters>
struct string_literal {
   static_assert(PassedLength == CountedLength, "Passed to STRING_LITERAL length does not match the length of string...");
};

#define STRING_LITERAL(N, str) string_literal<N, string_literal_length(str), STRING_LITERAL_##N(str)>

// ... as long as we need it ...
#define STRING_LITERAL_128(str) STRING_LITERAL_127(str), str[127]
#define STRING_LITERAL_127(str) STRING_LITERAL_126(str), str[126]
#define STRING_LITERAL_126(str) STRING_LITERAL_125(str), str[125]
#define STRING_LITERAL_125(str) STRING_LITERAL_124(str), str[124]
// ...
#define STRING_LITERAL_5(str) STRING_LITERAL_4(str), str[4]
#define STRING_LITERAL_4(str) STRING_LITERAL_3(str), str[3]
#define STRING_LITERAL_3(str) STRING_LITERAL_2(str), str[2]
#define STRING_LITERAL_2(str) STRING_LITERAL_1(str), str[1]
#define STRING_LITERAL_1(str) str[0]
```

Now usage:

```
template <class SLiteral>
struct usage_of_string_literal {
};

int main() {
   usage_of_string_literal<STRING_LITERAL(12, "123456789012")> uosl;
}
```

Unfortunately one have to provide the length of the string to get it work but it's still more comfortable solution than plain variadic arg template of chars, and the length is verified by the static_assert so the compiler can help to pick appropriate value...

---

**Edit**

One more template magic. This one is making use of short-circuit to get rid of the string size from STRING_LITERAL declaration (c++17):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

#define MAX_STRING_LITERAL_LENGTH 11
#define STRING_LITERAL(str) string_literal<char_pack<STRING_LITERAL_11(str)>>::s

#define STRING_LITERAL_11(str) STRING_LITERAL_10(str), ((TERMINATED_10(str))?(str[10]):('\0'))
#define STRING_LITERAL_10(str) STRING_LITERAL_9(str), ((TERMINATED_9(str))?(str[9]):('\0'))
#define STRING_LITERAL_9(str) STRING_LITERAL_8(str), ((TERMINATED_8(str))?(str[8]):('\0'))
#define STRING_LITERAL_8(str) STRING_LITERAL_7(str), ((TERMINATED_7(str))?(str[7]):('\0'))
#define STRING_LITERAL_7(str) STRING_LITERAL_6(str), ((TERMINATED_6(str))?(str[6]):('\0'))
#define STRING_LITERAL_6(str) STRING_LITERAL_5(str), ((TERMINATED_5(str))?(str[5]):('\0'))
#define STRING_LITERAL_5(str) STRING_LITERAL_4(str), ((TERMINATED_4(str))?(str[4]):('\0'))
#define STRING_LITERAL_4(str) STRING_LITERAL_3(str), ((TERMINATED_3(str))?(str[3]):('\0'))
#define STRING_LITERAL_3(str) STRING_LITERAL_2(str), ((TERMINATED_2(str))?(str[2]):('\0'))
#define STRING_LITERAL_2(str) STRING_LITERAL_1(str), ((TERMINATED_1(str))?(str[1]):('\0'))
#define STRING_LITERAL_1(str) str[0]


#define TERMINATED_10(str) TERMINATED_9(str) && str[9]
#define TERMINATED_9(str) TERMINATED_8(str) && str[8]
#define TERMINATED_8(str) TERMINATED_7(str) && str[7]
#define TERMINATED_7(str) TERMINATED_6(str) && str[6]
#define TERMINATED_6(str) TERMINATED_5(str) && str[5]
#define TERMINATED_5(str) TERMINATED_4(str) && str[4]
#define TERMINATED_4(str) TERMINATED_3(str) && str[3]
#define TERMINATED_3(str) TERMINATED_2(str) && str[2]
#define TERMINATED_2(str) TERMINATED_1(str) && str[1]
#define TERMINATED_1(str) str[0]

template <char... Cs>
struct char_pack {
    static constexpr char const arr[sizeof...(Cs) + 1] = {Cs..., 0};
    static constexpr std::size_t non_zero_count = (((Cs != 0)?1:0) + ...);
    static_assert(non_zero_count < MAX_STRING_LITERAL_LENGTH, "You need to create more macros");
};

template <char... Cs>
constexpr char const char_pack<Cs...>::arr[sizeof...(Cs) + 1];

template <char... Cs>
constexpr std::size_t char_pack<Cs...>::non_zero_count;

template <class CP, class = void, class = std::make_index_sequence<CP::non_zero_count>>
struct string_literal;

template <char... Cs, std::size_t... Is>
struct string_literal<char_pack<Cs...>, std::enable_if_t<(Cs && ...)>, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    static constexpr char const s[sizeof...(Cs) + 1] = {Cs..., '\0'};
};

template <char... Cs, std::size_t... Is> 
constexpr char const string_literal<char_pack<Cs...>, std::enable_if_t<(Cs && ...)>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>::s[sizeof...(Cs) + 1];

template <char... Cs, std::size_t... Is>
struct string_literal<char_pack<Cs...>, std::enable_if_t<!(Cs && ...)>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>: string_literal<char_pack<char_pack<Cs...>::arr[Is]...>> { };

template <const char *>
struct foo {};

int main() {
    foo<STRING_LITERAL("abcdefghij")> f;
    static_cast<void>(f);
}
```

[[live demo]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kVSG01hESlFCP044)

Comment: I think passing of length can be trivially removed by having yet another indirection macro .. `#define STRING_LITERAL_(STR) STRING_LITERAL(sizeof(STR) - 1, STR)`. Usage: `STRING_LITERAL_("123456789012")`. BTW, there is a boost facility as well, as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18154638/514235). However, your answer good that it provides readymade solution. You can also put a `const char` "array" inside the `class string_literal` which will simply recollect all the individual characters into string again.

Comment: Verified your code & it seems that whatever you have done is correct; i.e. we need to pass the length explicitly as a literal number for this code to work. I was under impression that, you have implemented the way boost's `MPLLIBS_STRING` is implemented. It seems that there has to be some complex trickery for that macro to work.

Comment: @iammilind I heard about `BOOST_HANA_STRING` but as far as I know it cannot be used in unevaluated context as it uses lambdas... I'll look up the  `MPLLIBS_STRING`. As for the length it cannot be exchanged with `sizeof` because I used concatenation to do simple extensible loop maybe they used some more complex preprocessor loop mechanism here...

Comment: This seems a great solution, though it doesn't compile on msvc: https://godbolt.org/z/9ssE83scW I'm trying to make it more portable, any suggestion is welcome :)

Answer (score 5):

You can "simulate" strings with C++11 variadic templates:

```
template<char... CHARS>
struct string
{
    operator const std::string&()
    {
        static const std::string str{ { CHARS... } };
        return str;
    }
}

int main()
{
    using my_string = string<'h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d','!','!','!'>;

    std::cout << my_string() << std::endl;
}
```

This prints:

> hello world!!!

Comment: Yes, I've tried it and it works but it isn't comfortable either. Anyway, my main question is: why won't the two snippets I posted work?