# Can I use the preprocessor to replace one type declaration with another?

Tags: c++, macros

The following code shows class `A`, `B`, and `C`. An `A` is the ctor argument to `B` and `C`.

Macro `X` conditionally creates either an `A` or a `B` instance.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
};

class B
{
public:
  B( const A& a ) : a_( a ) { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
private:
  const A& a_;
};

class C
{
public:
  C( const A& a, const std::string& file, int line )
    : b_( ( (std::cout << "@ " << file << ":" << line << std::endl), a ) )
  {
    std::cout << "After" << std::endl;
  }
private:
  B b_;
};

#undef DEBUG
#ifdef DEBUG
#define X( Z ) B b##Z( Z )
#else
#define X( Z ) C c##Z( Z, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#endif

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  A a;
  B b( a );
  C c( a, __FILE__, __LINE__ );
  X( a );
  return 0;
}
```

I was asked to rename `B` to `SomethingElse` and create a `B` macro such that all existing instances of `B b( a )` becomes either a `SomethingElse` or a `C`.

I don't think this ask can be satisfied because `SomethingElse` and `C` constructors have different signatures, so I cannot just do:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define B SomethingElse
#else
#define B C
#endif
```

Are there C preprocessor experts out there who can confirm whether or not there is a way to satisfy the ask? Can a macro be created such that all existing instantiations of `B` can be swapped at compile-time to instantiations of `SomethingElse` or `C`? You can assume the second and third arguments to `C` will be `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.

Comment: What a mess, I would look for another job if I was you.

Comment: Can you give an example of what calls to `B` constrictors that become `SomethingElse` and `C` should get replaced by?

Comment: @Davislor if `DEBUG` defined, then `B b( a )` becomes `SomethingElse somethingelse_a( a )`. If `DEBUG` undefined then `B b( a )` becomes `C c_a( a, __FILE__, __LINE__ )`. Like I said: I don't think it is possible, but I'm open to suggestion.

Comment: @StoneThrow I think it was aimed at your job place practices and was in good faith.

Comment: @StoneThrow I clearly understood that you are enforced to do this crap, did not realize my comment is ambiguous (English is not my first language, sorry for misunderstanding)

Comment: @Slava - Ok, sorry, Slava. It's hard to judge "tone" or "intent" given only text without any face-to-face. I was too quick to assume malicious intent - sorry for my misunderstanding as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly easy, once you realize that C++ inheritance implements an IS-A relation.

You define a new class `realB<const str* FILE, int LINE>`, which IS-A (derives from) either `C` or `SomethingElse`. The only small trick you need is a helper `constexpr const char*` to capture `__FILE__`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18031951/15416).

Now `realB<FILE, LINE>` has a ctor which takes only one parameter, `A a`, but if it inherits from `C` it can still pass `(a, FILE, LINE)` to `C::C`

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. I use "`template <int T>`" style templatization (as opposed to "`template <typename T>`") so rarely it'd never pop to mind when it makes itself useful. I have a rudimentary proof of concept working based on your answer, and I think I can parlay this to apply to the actual situation. Thank you; this was a clever angle to approach this from.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone, so this is untested, but you might try:

```
#if DEBUG
#  define CREATEB(a) somethingelse(a)
#else
#  define CREATEB(a) C( (a), __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#endif
```

These should work on the right-hand-side of an `auto` or reference-to-base-class declaration.