# Why passing a string literal to a template calling std::format fails to compile?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, rvalue-reference

The following code snippet fails to compile on the latest version of MSVC (Visual Studio 2022 17.2.2). The same snippet seemed to work just fine on previous compiler versions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

template <typename First, typename... Args>
inline auto format1(First&& first, Args&&... args) -> decltype(std::format(first, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return std::format(std::forward<First>(first), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << format1("hi {} {}", 123, 456);
}
```

The compiler emits the following error:

> 1>ConsoleApplication3.cpp(10,24): message : failure was caused by a
> read of a variable outside its lifetime
> 1>ConsoleApplication3.cpp(10,24): message : see usage of 'first'
> 1>ConsoleApplication3.cpp(14): message : see reference to function
> template instantiation 'std::string format<const
> char(&)[9],int,int>(First,int &&,int &&)' being compiled 1>
> with 1>        [ 1>            First=const char (&)[9] 1>        ]

It seems that somehow forwarding a string literal to std::format makes the compiler think that they are used outside of their lifetime. I tried changing the function to accept `const First& first` and all sorts of other variants but the error remains.

As far as I understand, when `First` is deduced to a const reference, its lifetime should be extended to the scope of the invoked function.

So why do I get this error? How can I fix this?

---

Further investigating this, it seems like something specific to the use of std::format.

This snippet works fine when provided with a string literal:

```
template <std::size_t COUNT>
inline auto format2(const char (&first)[COUNT])
{
    std::cout << first;
}
```

Wheras this one doesn't:

```
template <std::size_t COUNT>
inline auto format2(const char (&first)[COUNT])
{
    std::format(first);
}
```

Comment: [Passing a string literal as a type argument to a class template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033110/passing-a-string-literal-as-a-type-argument-to-a-class-template),  --->       [C-Style Strings as template arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826464/c-style-strings-as-template-arguments) and [Trying to pass string literals as template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031818/trying-to-pass-string-literals-as-template-arguments)

Comment: These issues are unrelated. I believe this problem is more specific to std::format implementation.

Comment: The issues _are_ related because you can reshape your function to receive the format as C-style string template argument and use it like:
    format2<"format{}">(2);
or via a macro:
    #define FMT(fmt, ...) format2<fmt>(__VA_ARGS__)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After [P2216](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2216r3.html), `std::format` requires that the format string must be a core constant expression. In your case, the compilation fails because the function argument `First` is not a constant expression.

The workaround is to use `std::vformat`, which works for runtime format strings

```
template<typename First, typename... Args>
auto format1(First&& first, Args&&... args) {
  return std::vformat(
    std::forward<First>(first),
    std::make_format_args(args...));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WGEKEEr4c)

If you really want to use `std::format`, you can pass in a lambda that returns a string literal

```
template<typename First, typename... Args>
auto format1(First first, Args&&... args) {
  return std::format(first(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << format1([]{ return "hi {} {}"; }, 123, 456);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n79P5G53a)

Comment: thanks, can you please explain why First is not a constant expression? can I somehow declare my template to correctly deduce a constant expression?

Comment: Note that arguments to make_format_args shouldn't be forwarded, see e.g. eel.is/c++draft/format#functions-2