# Hash function f(a, b) = f(b,a)

Tags: algorithm, hash

I need simple hash function that takes two parameters, with the following parameters:

- a,b,c,d are different strings (approximately 30 characters)
- f(a,b) = f(b,a)
- f(a,c) ≠ f(a,d)
- f(c,b) ≠ f(d,b)

Comment: Can you do your homework at home, alone, by yourself?

Comment: And you have tried....

Comment: `f(x, y) = md5(x ^ y)`, for example

Comment: @Raptor it's not my homework. I want to use it in my production code :) and I'm seeking the best solution.

Comment: @ghi in that case stack is not a coding service please do your own work and come back if you have issues with it.

Answer (score 2):

Sort and concatenate the two parameters (to ensure that `f(a,b)` equals `f(b,a)`. Since there are only two items to sort the result will be either `ab` or `ba`.

If the strings have the property that `ab` may equal `cd` (for example `strong` + `hearted` and `strongheart` + `ed`) you may want to "salt" the string by prepending it with the length of the first string coded in a fixed number of bytes.

Then apply a string hash on the result. [There are numerous examples online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595/what-is-a-good-hash-function).

Note that there is no guarantee that two different strings won't result in the same hash value, but a good hash algorithm will reduce the probability.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Is this answer incorrect? It looks correct to me (my first thought was to do this exact thing).

Comment: In addition to sorting, it's a good precaution to prepend the  strings before concatenation with the length of the strings. This is to prevent finding trivial collisions like `f("abc", "def") = f("ab", "cdef")`. I'd suggest prepending 4-byte int (instead of length in ascii string). So for example: `f(a,b) = h(len(a).to_bytes(4) + a + len(b).to_bytes(4) + b)` where a < b.

Comment: @LieRyan Thanks! I have improved my answer. (it is actually sufficient to include the length of the first string).