# how to "explain" the following hash function is bad

Tags: hash, modulo

we have a hash table with size 16, using double hashing method.

h1(x) = k mod 16

h2(x) = 2*(k mod 8)

I know that h2 hash function is bad, probably because mod 8 and times 2, but I don't know how to explain it. is there any explanation like "h2 hash function should mod prime or it will cause ____ problem "

Answer (score 1):

It is bad because it increases the number of collisions.

The (mod 8) means that you are only looking for 8 pigeonholes in your 16-pigeonhole table.

Multiplying it by 2 just spreads those 8 pigeonholes out so that you don’t have to search too many slots past the hashed index to find an empty hole...

**You should always compute modulo the size of your table.**

```
h(x) ::= x (mod N)   // where N is the table size
```

The purpose of making the table size a prime number just has to do with how powers of two are very common in computer science. If your data is random, then the size of the table doesn’t matter.

— As long as it is big enough for your expected load factor. A 16-element table is very small. You shouldn’t expect to store more than 6-12 *random* values in your table without a high-probability of collisions.

A very good linked thread is [What is a good Hash Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595/what-is-a-good-hash-function?rq=1), which is totally worth a read just for the links to further reading alone.